# WELD-001456 Argument bean must not be null

Tags: jsf, glassfish

I got this exception `Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalArgumentException: WELD-001456 Argument "resolvedBean" must not be null` and found the following on the web [here](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WELD-1387):

> This is an ordering issue in GlassFish. What happens is that the loadFlows() method of http://java.net/projects/mojarra/sources/svn/content/trunk/jsf-ri/src/main/java/com/sun/faces/application/ApplicationAssociate.java

is being invoked before WeldBootstrap.endInitialization() has finished. It is necessary to fully initialize Weld before invoking producers (which loadFlows() does).

What is that ordering issue? I mean which libraries need to be on top and load earlier?
I build a jsf 2.2 web application with glassfish 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had two ocpsoft rewrite jar files in glassfish4.0/glassfish/lib and glassfish4.0/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib that initialized before weld. I deleted them both and got rid of that exception.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is the only stack overflow question with this error message, I wanted to share my problem in case someone else had the same error but different problem.

I had a maven dependency that included org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.5 as a runtime exception. I explicitly added the transitive httpclient dependency into my pom and it fixed my problem.